# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client [node and express js]--

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, nodejs-server

I am trying to get data by Id records saved in mssql database. for eg. I am forming a get request in postman like this: *localhost:3200/api/v1/players*
Problem is I am getting error displayed as follows:

```
node:_http_outgoing:576
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Why is it so? Is it because some other query is also running when I am visiting that endpoint?

My code for querying by data:

```
const getPlayerById=async(req, res, next)=>
{
    try
    {
        const id = req.params.id;

        sql.connect(config, function(err)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                var req=new sql.Request();

                 var player=req.input('input_parameter', sql.BigInt, id)
                            .query("select distinct * from players WHERE Id=@input_parameter", function(err, recordset)
                            {
                                if(err)
                                {
                                    console.log("Error while querying for Id!: "+err)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    res.send(recordset);
                                }

                            });
            }
            return res.send("Record fetched for selected player!");
            
        });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

In my main server.js I have wired up

```
app.use('/api/v1', playerRoutes.routes);
```

In router file:

```
router.get('/players/:id', playerControll.getPlayerById)
```

The record being displayed in my postman response window is like:

***Could not send request
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3200***

***************************EDIT*************************************
Now the query is working, but I am getting the fetched record being displayed twice in a nested format!!

Like this->

```
{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "Id": 6,
                "player_code": "P006",
                "player_name": "Petr Cech",
                "player_club": "Chelsea",
                "player_position": "Goalkeeper"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "Id": 6,
            "player_code": "P006",
            "player_name": "Petr Cech",
            "player_club": "Chelsea",
            "player_position": "Goalkeeper"
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": []
}
```

What's the glitch now?? Why is it showing like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error, simply because the `res.send(recordset);` line is executed before the `return res.send("Record fetched for selected player!");`

Maybe you should add a `return` keyword to have `return res.send(recordset);`

Comment: hi @SebastienH please take a look at the edited portion of main post under EDIT;

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury the edit section is a different issue than the original question. you should probably return the `recordset` property of your `recordset` result parameter.

Comment: hi @SebastienH yep --- I opened a separate question:   
  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74305542/fetched-record-from-mssql-database-being-displayed-twice-in-postman-response-win

Comment: btw i would recommend applying your own standard for the API output format, with props like `{ message, data, status, errors etc..}`

Comment: yes, it works if I put --->    return res.send(recordset.recordset[0]);

returns the fetched data 1ce as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect successfully to the database, and the query returns results without error, you are sending the results back with:

```
res.send(recordset)
```

But also, regardless if the connection with the database is established or not, you are sending back a message:

```
return res.send("Record fetched for selected player!");
```

res.send() can only be called only once per request.

Comment: ok, in that case @Paul, I'll replace it with a console.log message;