# Fetched record from mssql database being displayed twice in POSTMAN response window --

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, postman

I am querying the database for fetching record based on a selected id value from my node and express backend app. The glitch is that the record is being displayed twice in nested format in the response window of POSTMAN, which I use to built the request urls.

For ease of understanding, my getPlayerById code is as

```
const getPlayerById=async(req, res, next)=>
{
    const id = req.params.id;

    sql.connect(config, function(error)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            var req=new sql.Request();

            var player=req.input('input_parameter', sql.BigInt, id)
                            .query("select distinct * from players WHERE Id=@input_parameter", function(err, recordset)
                            {
                                if(err)
                                {
                                    console.log("Error while querying for Id!: "+err)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return res.send(recordset);
                                }

                            });
        }
    });
}
```

and as response I am getting

```
{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "player_code": "P003",
                "player_name": "Florent Malouda",
                "player_club": "Chelsea",
                "player_position": "Winger"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "player_code": "P003",
            "player_name": "Florent Malouda",
            "player_club": "Chelsea",
            "player_position": "Winger"
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": []
}
```

for a url of

```
localhost:3200/api/v1/players/3
```

What needs to be done? Why is the data being shown twice like that? For showing proper output? I tried doing res.recordsets.recordset but it returns gibberish error.
Some help needed!

Comment: Hey all; I used return res.send(recordset.recordset[0]) and getting the response in desired manner json format and only 1ce too. This worked for me.